# How to compute the joint probablity of a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to compute the joint probability of the csv file and return a new csv file that has an additional column of the joint probability. The problem is my csv file has some nans in it and I would like that the rows that contains nan to have a joint probability as well.
My csv input file looks like  : ( this is just a subset)

```
Age,Salary
84.0,74198.0
25.5,57881.5
41.0,NaN
57.0,NaN
54.0,40286.0
```

The csv output file look like :

```
Age,Salary,JointProbability
84.0,74198.0,0.04000000000000001
25.5,57881.5,0.04000000000000001
41.0,,0.0
57.0,,0.0
54.0,40286.0,0.04000000000000001
```

The desired csv output : ( the probabilities randomly so that they must sum up to 1) I also want the additional column that has the probabilities to be called P(column names of the input csv file) which could change depending on the input csv file. I also want the NaN to be there instead of blank space as in the previous fie

```
Age,Salary,P(Age,Salary)
84.0,74198.0,0.3
25.5,57881.5,0.1
41.0,NaN,0.1
57.0,NaN,0.2
54.0,40286.0,0.3
```

The code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('random_sampled_data.csv')

# Calculate joint probabilities
joint_probabilities = []
total_count = len(df)

# Calculate joint probability for each row
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    
    for column in df.columns:
        probability = len(df[df[column] == row[column]]) / total_count
    joint_probabilities.append(probability)

# Add joint probabilities as a new column to the DataFrame
df['JointProbability'] = joint_probabilities

# Save the updated DataFrame to a new CSV file
df.to_csv('output_with_joint_probabilities.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Try `value_counts` with `dropna=False`, divided by N.

Answer (score 0):

creating a new column with the probabilities, taking into account rows with NaN values, and to calculate the joint probability of a CSV file. ,

**I modified your the code like this :**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv('input_file.csv')

joint_probabilities = []
total_count = len(df)


for _, row in df.iterrows():
    probability = 1
    for column in df.columns:
        if pd.isna(row[column]):
            probability *= 0.1  
        else:
            count = len(df[df[column] == row[column]])
            probability *= count / total_count
    joint_probabilities.append(probability)


joint_probabilities = np.array(joint_probabilities)
joint_probabilities /= joint_probabilities.sum()


df['P(' + ', '.join(df.columns) + ')'] = joint_probabilities


df.to_csv('output_file.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: the pd.isna function is used to check for NaN values in each row. If a NaN value is found, a probability of 0.1 is assigned to it. Otherwise, the count of rows with the same value in the same column is calculated, and the probability is multiplied by this count divided by the total count of rows. The probabilities are then normalized so they sum up to 1. Finally, the joint probabilities are added as a new column to the DataFrame with a name based on the column names of the input CSV file, and the updated DataFrame is saved to a new CSV file.

Comment: the joint probability is computed as : count of occurrence of the (row / total ) number of rows. so if the total number of rows is 5 and there is two occurrences of the row 25, nan , then the assigned probably must be 2/5. similarly if I have one occurrence of the row 31, 3553 then the assigned probability should be 1/5. I dont want to assign a fixed value if the row contains nan

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing in an alternate answer:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,3], 'B':[1,2,np.nan,np.nan]})

colNameJoiningKeyName     = 'colJoiningKey'
colNameJointProbabilities = 'JointProbability'

df[colNameJoiningKeyName] = df[[colName for colName in df.columns if colName!=colNameJoiningKeyName]].astype(str).sum(axis = 1)
frequencyDict             = df[colNameJoiningKeyName].value_counts(normalize=True).to_dict()

df[colNameJointProbabilities] = df[colNameJoiningKeyName].map(frequencyDict)
del df[colNameJoiningKeyName]

print(df)
```